# Why am I seeing "Nodetool status connection refused"?

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra

I've installed Cassandra via a service on an EC2 instance running Ubuntu 16, and I can't, for the life of me, understand why I can't get nodetool status working.

I've heard that I should change the cassanda-env.sh to include the hostname, which I have done here;

```
# add this if you're having trouble connecting:
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost"
```

However when I run `nodetool status`

I get

```
nodetool: Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused (Connection refused)'.
```

I've checked my security group, and I allow all traffic from anywhere and everywhere, I've even added a custom TCP rule to allow traffic for port 7199 and I still get connection refused.

I can ping localhost just fine;

```
PING localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.033 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.011 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.013 ms
```

And Cassandra is definitely running

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-20-215:~$ sudo service cassandra status
● cassandra.service - LSB: distributed storage system for structured data
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/cassandra; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Sun 2017-05-07 05:27:10 UTC; 2min 13s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 30370 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/cassandra stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 30521 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/cassandra start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

May 07 05:27:10 ip-172-31-20-215 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: distributed storage system for structured data...
May 07 05:27:10 ip-172-31-20-215 systemd[1]: Started LSB: distributed storage system for structured data.
```

I' not sure what more I can do, i've tried setting the host to another interface, however I still get the same problem. I don't even have IPtables installed so I really don't think it's a firewall issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Debug log after restart
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/263e1ee09d95dc761abaf39d8d3bcb1f

Comment: Cassandra status is exited and not definitely running...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out, you can't run Cassandra on a VPS with 512MB of RAM, you'll need at least 2GB, even with single-node cluster.

Cassandra was stopping seconds after starting, and I couldn't nodetool status because it wasn't running.

Comment: this is definitely the best and right answer to this mysterious issue! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It's a RAM issue, I faced same today and solved the problem after changing EC2 instance type to Medium.

Comment: I am running a single node cluster no prod data on t2.medium still getting ubuntu@ip-172-21-0-111:~$ nodetool status
nodetool: Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused (Connection refused)'.

Answer (score 2):

1. Get rid of this line: JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost"
2. Try restart the service: **sudo service cassandra restart**
3. If you have a cluster, make sure that ports 7000 and 9042 are open within your security group.

Comment: No luck, same issue [code]nodetool: Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused (Connection refused)'.[/code]

Comment: Can you please restart the server and review logs for any errors? If there's any, attach them to the question.

Comment: I've added the debug log, another user pointed out that cassandra was not running, but I can't see any errors in the log file; only warnings

Comment: How did you installed cassandra? Can you try to run cqlsh? And also, try to run sudo nodetool status.

Comment: Hey mate, it was a RAM issue. My EC2 instance only had 512Mb of RAM and Cassandra was stopping almost immediately after starting.

Comment: And there wasn't any errors in system or debug logs?

Comment: There were WARNs DEBUGs and INFOs but no actual ERRORs in the debug log

Comment: And in system log?

Comment: @Cherona how much RAM is required? I have a single node cluster no prod data !  ubuntu@ip-172-21-0-111:~$ free -g
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:              3           0           3           0           0           3
Swap:             0           0           0

Comment: @Cherona which log did you checked for RAM info as I am seeing nothing ubuntu@ip-172-21-0-111:~$ tail -f /var/log/cassandra/system.log
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2020-04-10 08:10:23,853 Server.java:182 - Stop listening for CQL clients
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2020-04-10 08:10:23,854 Gossiper.java:1500 - Announcing shutdown
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2020-04-10 08:10:23,855 StorageService.java:2169 - Node /172.21.0.111 state jump to shutdown