# cassandra.service exits after a few seconds and nodetool gives 'Connection refused' error

Tags: java, cassandra, digital-ocean, cassandra-3.0, nodetool

I have a 4GB RAM ubuntu server on digitalocean
I am using cassandra 3.9

After going through the setup process detailed [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-cassandra-and-run-a-single-node-cluster-on-ubuntu-14-04)

cqlsh, nodetool status all return back this message:

> nodetool: Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused (Connection refused)'.

I have read several similar issues and they all suggested 4GB minimum ram size, I have that but still get the same error >>
[Nodetool status connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43828168/nodetool-status-connection-refused)

Some suggest to set listen_address and rpc_address to digitalocean assigned ip in cassandra.yaml, also tried that, but problem persists

some suggest looking at debuglogs & systemlogs, Alot of [INFO] and [DEBUG] lines, but I have some [WARN] lines, which dont terminate the execution and it terminates at an [ERROR] line

**Warnings**

```
...
WARN  [main] 2018-03-13 12:06:52,359 DatabaseDescriptor.java:563 - Small commitlog volume detected at /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog; setting commitlog_total_space_in_mb to 6158.  You can override this in cassandra.yaml
WARN  [main] 2018-03-13 12:06:52,361 DatabaseDescriptor.java:590 - Small cdc volume detected at /var/lib/cassandra/cdc_raw; setting cdc_total_space_in_mb to 3079. You can override this in cassandra.yaml
WARN  [main] 2018-03-13 12:06:52,365 DatabaseDescriptor.java:643 - Only 22.102GiB free across all data volumes. Consider adding more capacity to your cluster or removing obsolete snapshots
...

WARN  [main] 2018-03-13 12:06:52,530 StartupChecks.java:123 - jemalloc shared library could not be preloaded to speed up memory allocations
WARN  [main] 2018-03-13 12:06:52,530 StartupChecks.java:156 - JMX is not enabled to receive remote connections. Please see cassandra-env.sh for more info.
INFO  [main] 2018-03-13 12:06:52,533 SigarLibrary.java:44 - Initializing SIGAR library
WARN  [main] 2018-03-13 12:06:52,554 SigarLibrary.java:174 - Cassandra server running in degraded mode. Is swap disabled? : true,  Address space adequate? : true,  nofile limit adequate? : true, nproc limit adequate? : false
```

**Error**

```
...
ERROR [main] 2018-03-13 12:06:55,808 CassandraDaemon.java:747 - Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.cassandra.utils.JMXServerUtils$Exporter.exportObject(Ljava/rmi/Remote;ILjava/rmi/server/RMIClientSocketFactory;Ljava/rmi/ser$
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIJRMPServerImpl.export(RMIJRMPServerImpl.java:150) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIJRMPServerImpl.export(RMIJRMPServerImpl.java:135) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.start(RMIConnectorServer.java:405) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.JMXServerUtils.createJMXServer(JMXServerUtils.java:106) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.maybeInitJmx(CassandraDaemon.java:145) [apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:219) [apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:601) [apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:730) [apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
```

Not sure what to do with that error message

I suspect many of you have had this issue, and some of you solved it
please clearly detail for the rest of us (and future folks) how you sorted it

I am considering trying an earlier version of cassandra, maybe this problem is specific to version 3.9 and not earlier ones

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue ([CASSANDRA-14173](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14173)).  Either downgrade Java to Java 8 build 152, or upgrade the Cassandra.

Comment: I upgraded my cassandra from **3.9** to **3.11.2** and it looks like the problem is solved, the service stays alive without exiting, thx!